# Compute Engine reason for application recycling

Tags: asp.net-core, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, program-entry-point

I have setup logging for my ASP.NET Core enabled Compute Engine Instance. I find that at seemingly random times, the `public static void Main(string[] args)` method is re-entered. I have been told that this is due to application recycling.

Is this behaviour a result of my code failing? Is it scheduled? and how do I prevent it/determing the cause?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this behaviour a result of my code failing?

No, this is normal housekeeping by IIS. Your app is idle and IIS has decided to release and restart your application. One of the reasons is to free up memory. Another is preventing memory leaks from slowly consuming all memory.

> Is it scheduled?

This is controlled by `Idle Timeout`. You can make this longer or shorter. I don't recommending changing this setting. Think about why you need your program to run when nothing is happening (it is idle).

> and how do I prevent it/determing the cause?

You can disable recycling or delay it by changing `Idle Timeout`.

Comment: The reason I am surprised that the IIS thinks it’s idle is because I have a scheduled task that makes a get request to the site every 30 minutes. What determines whether IIS has been “idle”?

Comment: Check the Idle Timeout setting. I think that the default is 20 minutes.

Comment: I apologise, I thought finding the seeting would be straight forward. How do I find the setting in Windows Server 2016?

Comment: It is located in IIS under the "Process Model" section. I currently do not have IIS running so I am pulling this location from memory.